# highlighting object property in metro console.log

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have to console.log a big object in metro and I would like to highlight an specific property. For example:

```
let bigObject = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4};
console.log(bigObject)
```

And when I console.log the whole thing, I would like to highlight property "c":

[image]

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Why not just log out c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This should work, however, you will need to print them separately:

```js
let bigObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
console.log(bigObject.a);
console.log(bigObject.b);
console.log('%c' + bigObject.c, 'background: blue; color: white');
console.log(bigObject.d);
```

**It seems that the snippet doesn´t support the console style.**

- Using a `forEach()` loop:

```js
let bigObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

Object.keys(bigObject).forEach(e => {
  if (e === 'c')  console.log('%c' + e + ": " + bigObject[e], 'background: blue; color: white');
  else  console.log(e + ": " + bigObject[e]);
});
```

More info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#usage

Comment: I think a ```for loop``` will do a better job.